# android: Put Text into a TextBox in Webview

Tags: android, button, text, webview

I write an app for android. There is a Webview and I want to put Text into the focussed TextArea on the website after clicking a button at my app. I haven't found any solution at google.

It is important to put in the text, it is no login view, where data can be transmitted by the POST methode, the user should be able to see the input.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> public void addJavascriptInterface (Object object, String name)
>   Added in API level 1
>   Injects the supplied Java object into this WebView. The object is injected into the JavaScript context of the main frame, using the supplied name. This allows the Java object's methods to be accessed from JavaScript. For applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above, only public methods that are annotated with JavascriptInterface can be accessed from JavaScript. For applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN or below, all public methods (including the inherited ones) can be accessed, see the important security note below for implications.
>   Note that injected objects will not appear in JavaScript until the page is next (re)loaded. For example:

```
class JsObject {
@JavascriptInterface
public String toString() { return "injectedObject"; }
}
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
webView.loadData("", "text/html", null);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(injectedObject.toString())");
```

IMPORTANT:

This method can be used to allow JavaScript to control the host application. This is a powerful feature, but also presents a security risk for applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN or below, because JavaScript could use reflection to access an injected object's public fields. Use of this method in a WebView containing untrusted content could allow an attacker to manipulate the host application in unintended ways, executing Java code with the permissions of the host application. Use extreme care when using this method in a WebView which could contain untrusted content.
JavaScript interacts with Java object on a private, background thread of this WebView. Care is therefore required to maintain thread safety.
The Java object's fields are not accessible.
Parameters
object  the Java object to inject into this WebView's JavaScript context. Null values are ignored.
name    the name used to expose the object in JavaScript

I am using phone, sorry for formating. This is quote from offical page android. 
So:
If is your page:

1. Set ID of Input, for example text (for example: <input id="text" ...)
2. Add this code of end of document:

   <script>function a(b){document.getElementById("text (here is yur ID)").value=b;};function b(a){document.getElementById("text (here is your ID)").value+=a;}</script>
3. To change text, use this code:

   String str="any string";
   webview.loadUrl("javascript:a(\""+str+"\")");
4. To add text at the end:

   String str="any string";
   webview.loadUrl("javascript:b(\""+str+"\")");

Comment: cool, thank you. But the site is not mine. Cant I input the text without modifiing the site?

Comment: Yes, you can. But can you give me code or url? You can also get all inputs and check, what edit.

Comment: it is a math forum (german) and i want to have a horizontal scrollbar on the top of the screen (with image buttons), where the user can input mathematik operators (+,*,-...) without changing to the second part of the keyboard. I use the android.webkit.WebView Client. The website is [www.gute-mathe-fragen.de](http://www.gute-mathe-fragen.de) . Because the char is also a button on the keyboard, maybe i can simulate a keyboard press? What do you mean with get al inputs and check, what edit.

Comment: Is it input text next to 'Daine Mathefrage'? If it is, use this code:

Comment: WebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('askboxin').value+='"+charToAddAtEnd+"'");

Comment: so, you can't get focused field, but you can register action 'onFocus' and save focused field, next add text to saved focused field.